# Making and keeping part of a cell bold - Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want a cell in my spreadsheet to make part of the cell bold.  I found a similar post.  It does work, to a degree.  It works the first time the cell is updated, but if the cell is updated, everything becomes bold.  I used the method described in the above link in the first two columns (cases 9 and 10 in the switch statement), but would do not want to update the other columns until I have something that works correctly

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim comment As String
Dim time As String
Dim StartCell As String
Dim EndCell As String
Dim pos As Integer
Dim newComment As String

If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then
   Exit Sub
End If

StartCell = "A" & Target.Row
EndCell = "W" & Target.Row
time = Target.Value
time = Format(Target.Value, "h:mm AM/PM")
comment = Range("S" & Target.Row).Value
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("I4:R254")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        Select Case Target.Column
            Case 9
                newComment = time & " EST Tech on site, initial prep, SW and SO# verified"
                pos = InStr(newComment, "EST")

                If comment = "" Then
                     Range("S" & Target.Row) = time & " EST Tech on site, initial prep, SW and SO# verified"
                     Range("S" & Target.Row).Characters(Start:=1, Length:=pos - 1).Font.Bold = True
                Else
                    Range("S" & Target.Row) = time & " EST Tech on site, initial prep, SW and SO# verified" & Chr(10) & comment
                    Range("S" & Target.Row).Characters(Start:=1, Length:=pos - 1).Font.Bold = True
                End If

                Range("R" & Target.Row) = "In Progress"

            Case 10
                newComment = time & " EST Installing HW" & Chr(10) & comment
                pos = InStr(newComment, "EST")
                If Range("J" & Target.Row).Value < Range("I" & Target.Row).Value Then
                    MsgBox ("Time for Checkpoint 2 must be greater than Checkpoint 1")
                    Target.Value = ""
                    Target.Select
                Else
                    Range("S" & Target.Row) = time & " EST Installing HW" & Chr(10) & comment
                    Range("S" & Target.Row).Characters(Start:=1, Length:=pos - 1).Font.Bold = True
                End If

            Case 11
                If Range("K" & Target.Row).Value < Range("J" & Target.Row).Value Then
                    MsgBox ("Time for Checkpoint 3 must be greater than Checkpoint 2")
                    Target.Value = ""
                    Target.Select
                Else
                    Range("S" & Target.Row) = time & " EST Phase 1 SW Installation" & Chr(10) & comment
                End If
            Case 12
               If Range("L" & Target.Row).Value < Range("K" & Target.Row).Value Then
                    MsgBox ("Time for Checkpoint 4 must be greater than Checkpoint 3")
                    Target.Value = ""
                    Target.Select
                Else
                    Range("S" & Target.Row) = time & " EST Running TPM and checking devices" & Chr(10) & comment
                End If
            Case 13
                If Range("M" & Target.Row).Value < Range("L" & Target.Row).Value Then
                    MsgBox ("Time for Checkpoint 5 must be greater than Checkpoint 4")
                    Target.Value = ""
                    Target.Select
                Else
                    Range("S" & Target.Row) = time & " EST Phase 2 SW Installation" & Chr(10) & comment
                End If
            Case 14
                If Range("N" & Target.Row).Value < Range("M" & Target.Row).Value Then
                    MsgBox ("Time for Checkpoint 6 must be greater than Checkpoint 5")
                    Target.Value = ""
                    Target.Select
                Else
                    Range("S" & Target.Row) = time & " EST Post Imaging Tasks" & Chr(10) & comment
                End If
            Case 15
                If Range("O" & Target.Row).Value < Range("N" & Target.Row).Value Then
                    MsgBox ("Time for Checkpoint 7 must be greater than Checkpoint 6")
                    Target.Value = ""
                    Target.Select
                Else
                    Range("S" & Target.Row) = time & " EST Upgrade Complete" & Chr(10) & comment
                    Range("R" & Target.Row) = "Complete"
                End If

            Case 18
                Select Case Target.Value
                    Case ""
                        Range(StartCell, EndCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                        Range(StartCell, EndCell).Font.ColorIndex = 1
                    Case "Pending"
                        Range(StartCell, EndCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                        Range(StartCell, EndCell).Font.ColorIndex = 1
                    Case "En Route"
                        Range(StartCell, EndCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
                        Range(StartCell, EndCell).Font.ColorIndex = 1
                    Case "In Progress"
                        Range(StartCell, EndCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
                        Range(StartCell, EndCell).Font.ColorIndex = 1
                    Case "Complete"
                        Range(StartCell, EndCell).Interior.Color = RGB(84, 130, 53)
                        Range(StartCell, EndCell).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 204)
                    Case "Cancelled"
                        Range(StartCell, EndCell).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                    Case "Rescheduled"
                        Range(StartCell, EndCell).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
                        Range(StartCell, EndCell).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                    Case "Carryover"
                        Range(StartCell, EndCell).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 153, 255)
                        Range(StartCell, EndCell).Font.ColorIndex = 3

                  End Select
            End Select
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

If there's anyway you can avoid formatting characters individually, you should. You'll spend a lot of time on it and just when you think you've got it, someone will figure a way to break it.  Like if you just put the time in it's own cell, you'd be a lot happier. Having said that, this gets you close and you may be able to tweak it from there.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim rLog As Range
    Dim sInput As String
    Dim aMsg(1 To 7) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sTime As String
    Dim lBoldEnd As Long

    Const TIMESAVE As String = "EDT"

    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then
       Exit Sub
    End If

    aMsg(1) = "Tech on site, initial prep, SW and SO# verified"
    aMsg(2) = "Installing HW"
    aMsg(3) = "Phase 1 SW Installation"
    aMsg(4) = "Running TPM and checking devices"
    aMsg(5) = "Phase 2 SW Installation"
    aMsg(6) = "Post Imaging Tasks"
    aMsg(7) = "Upgrade Complete"

    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("I4:O254")) Is Nothing Then
        If Not IsEmpty(Target.Value) Then
            If Target.Column > 9 And Target.Value < Target.Offset(0, -1).Value Then
                MsgBox "Time for checkpoint " & Target.Column - 8 & " must be less than time for checkpoint " & Target.Column - 7
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                    Target.ClearContents
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            Else
                Set rLog = Me.Cells(Target.Row, 19) 's
                sTime = Format(Target.Value, "hh:mm AM/PM """ & TIMESAVE & """")
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                    rLog.Font.Bold = False
                    If IsEmpty(rLog.Value) Then
                        rLog.Value = sTime & Space(1) & aMsg(Target.Column - 8)
                    Else
                        rLog.Value = sTime & Space(1) & aMsg(Target.Column - 8) & Chr$(10) & rLog.Value
                    End If
                    rLog.Characters(1, Len(sTime)).Font.Bold = True
                    For i = Len(sTime) To Len(rLog.Value)
                        If Mid$(rLog.Value, i, 1) = Chr$(10) Then
                            lBoldEnd = InStr(1, Mid$(rLog.Value, i + 1, Len(rLog.Value)), TIMESAVE) + Len(TIMESAVE)
                            If lBoldEnd > 0 Then
                                rLog.Characters(i + 1, lBoldEnd).Font.Bold = True
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next i
                    rLog.WrapText = True
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

For your column 18 stuff, you should just use Conditional Formatting rather than doing it in the code. Also, it's daylight time, if that matters to you.

Comment: But you can't put the time in its own cell because each entry isn't its own cell. I just realized that.

Comment: Thank you, yes that will get me closer to resolving this.  My apologies for the hackish code. I just started playing with VBA a few weeks ago.

Comment: Thank you for your help, This me closer than I was before.  But there are two issues.  First, I would like the entire time (ex 9:00 AM EDT) in bold.  Second, when an additional comment is added, only the numbers remain in bold.

Comment: You want only the numbers? Or the entire time? Or the entire time on the first one, but only the numbers after that?

Comment: I want the complete time entry, hh:mm AP/PM EDT.  I added EDT to the sTime variable and it works the first time something is entered, but after that it only keeps the numbers bold.

Comment: OK, I get it now. I changed the code. There's a constant where you can put EST or EDT. Instead of looking for the first space after a line break, it now looks for EST or EDT and bolds all the way through that.

Comment: Thank you!  That's great!  I'll clean up the conditional formatting and keep working on the rest of the wishlist for this worksheet.